# Geometry node instance UVmap problem

Tags: geometry-nodes

I tried to make a series of tables with geometry nodes, with the idea of being able to vary the size and distance between them (with a bit of noise).
The problem is that I cannot create the UV map.

[image]

Comment: Hi, nomad, it would tempt folks to commit to a download if you showed them a picture of where you're at, so far.